# Oracle 9 database as data source in SSRS 2017 ver 14.0

Tags: oracle, reporting-services, oracle9i

We recently install SSRS report server on a Windows Server 2016. We are trying to add a Oracle 9 instance as a data source of SSRS but we have not been succesful to do so. We installed:

1. Oracle Client 11G R2
2. ODAC 11G 32 bits
3. ODAC 11G 64 bits

Yet, with this, Oracle was not available as a connection type on SSRS web portal. We tried then to add a new connection with Data Tools for SSRS and it 'worked', supposedly ... it was deployed and we were able to see it as a connection type. However, it still won't work.

On Microsoft documentation they say to use ODAC 12c, but, I know from past experiences that Oracle 9 isn't compatible with client version 12. Nevertheless, we also tried installing it, both 32 and 64 bits version and we still can't figure out how to use Oracle as a data source.

Comment: You missed: Install the Data Provider for .NET 4.  ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-data/oracle-connection-type-ssrs?view=sql-server-2017  and https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/win.112/e23174/InstallODP.htm#ODPNT150

Comment: @Brian Hello, if I understand correctly, ODACs should includes ODP.NET for .NET 4.

Comment: How did you install the Client and ODAC? Compare with this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24104210/badimageformatexception-this-will-occur-when-running-in-64-bit-mode-with-the-32#24120100

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this: [Client / Server Interoperability Support Matrix for Different Oracle Versions (Doc ID 207303.1)](https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocumentDisplay?id=207303.1)

[image]

[image]

> #5 - For connections between 10.2 (or higher) and 9.2 the 9.2 end MUST be at 9.2.0.4 or higher. Connections between 10.2 (or higher) and 9.2.0.1, 9.2.0.2 or 9.2.0.3 have never been supported.

Comment: Yeah. ODAC 12c (recommended by Microsoft), won't work with Oracle 9. It seems like our best guest will be to try an OLE DB connection.

Comment: I think your main problem is that you use an almost 20 years old unsupported Oracle database version.